# Internship, probation or training in an academic setting

Tags: meaning

A translator have officially translated my non-English transcript to English. He has translated my training period "Probation". Is it correct in an academic setting? I read this in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probation_%28workplace%29): "... students with unsatisfactory grades may also be placed on academic probation by their institution."

Answer (score 2):

**Training** implies that most (if not all) of your time is spent learning rather than doing "useful work" for your employer.

**Intership** implies that you're doing "useful work" and contributing to your workplace, but also learning at the same time. It's sort of a mix of the other two.

**Probation** implies that you're more or less completely doing "useful work", but that the company is just giving you a trial period to check that you know what you're doing, that you're a good worker etc.

If probation is the right one, I wouldn't worry about the negative meaning you mentioned. I can't say for sure, since I don't live in the US, but I'm 99% sure that as long as you make it's clear that it's probation at a workplace, nobody will associate it with the sort of probation you get when you're released from prison.

Comment: Is the mentioned meaning true in an academic setting as well?

Comment: In an academic setting, I'd use the word "internship". I've never heard "training" or "probation" used to refer to the academic world.

Comment: were you taking training classes, or working while being trained?  were you paid or not? Did you have a mentor? Is this in a strictly book-learning (or online) situation or was it "hands-on" practice of some profession/activity?