# Probationary period vs trial period in employment contract

Tags: terminology

Some employment contracts have a period of, e.g., 2 months where either party is free to terminate the contract without needing to motivate their choice.

This is meant as a trial period for the company to see whether the employee performs, and for the employee to see whether they like working at the company.

What's the correct terminology for such a period? I've seen both *probationary period* and *trial period* mentioned on the internet, and didn't notice a clear conceptual difference between the two.

For example:

- The US Department of Health and Human services [mentions and defines both](https://www.hhs.gov/about/agencies/asa/ohr/hr-library/315-1/index.html), but the differences don't seem meaningful outside of the HHS' own context.
- The Dutch government [calls it a *trial period*](https://business.gov.nl/regulation/trial-period/).
- Wikipedia seems to prefer [probation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probation_(workplace)).

Comment: Related, but not an answer to this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47756/internship-probation-or-training-in-an-academic-setting

Comment: I think the correct terminology depends on the country and/or state.  In the USA, the practical meaning will also depend on the employment law of the state and of the wording of the contract itself, making this question rather superfluous.  I suggest you ask this question in the [Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not an employment lawyer, but I would understand a probationary period as a chance for the company to make sure that the employee is suitable, _not_ the other way round.

Comment: trial period and probationary period are the same thing. probation is something else, on its own.

Comment: In US, most of the labor contracts are [at-will employment](https://worldpopulationreview.com/state-rankings/at-will-employment-states).With such contracts, an employer can terminate an employee for any reason without warning. Therefore [trial periods](https://uk.indeed.com/career-advice/starting-new-job/work-trial-period) are useless.

Answer (score 1):

This article is specific to New Zeeland law, but the general principles should generally apply elsewhere:

> Probationary periods do not prevent an employee from raising a personal grievance for unjustified dismissal, which is one of the key differences compared to a trial period clause.
> There’s no maximum length for probation periods. This will depend on what is reasonable in your particular situation.
> …
> A trial period clause effect is far greater and places restrictions on the employee’s rights. This clause, if applied correctly can prevent an employee bringing a personal grievance for unjustified dismissal at the end of a trial period.
> — [Trial vs. probationary periods - what's the difference? - Duncan Cotterill](https://duncancotterill.com/insights/trial-vs-probationary-periods-whats-the-difference/)

The difference seems to be that for probation, performance *confirms that* employees are a good fit for the job, whereas a trial *determines whether* they are a good fit.

For instance, if I hire you as my accountant, I'm assuming that you are competent for the job.
Your probationary period is simply to verify that you are as good as your résumé says you are.
The expectation on both our parts is that you *will* retain the position.

But if I hire you for a position for which you have no previous experience, I am not assuming that you will be competent.
Your trial period is to determine whether you have sufficient skills to pick up what needs to be learned.
We both hope, but have no expectation, that you will pass the test.